# phonegap run android command erases all the changes in the app

Tags: cordova

I installed phonegap from CLI and everything is fine but when I try to start the app like this:

```
>phonegap run android
```

compiles android , installs app and the app starts on the devise,
but all the changes i made in the files of my app are erased and the app gets back to
it's virgin state.But if i run the app from eclipse in the sdk tool, it runs fine with the changes i made. I must have been doing something terribly wrong or i just did not understand the basics at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, perhaps, you are making the changes in the platforms/ folder and not in the root www folder for your project. Every time Phonegap rebuilds your project, your source files are injected into the platform-specific folder (in this case, Android java project) from your main www folder (and subfolders).

Comment: yes that was exactly what i was doing, i just found out.But as i everything was working fine, for no reason when i ran again, an error was thrown,saying that javac is not in my path which is wrong, i have everything set up already. I couldn't figure out the reason and i have re-installed JDK along JRE,ANT and nodejs,and set correct paths(JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME and also platform tools and tools,nodejs in path variable),i get an error in adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/config.xml file.No matter how much i try,i fail to install ,which i did before many times, Thank you for the response.

Comment: Now i am able to run the app from sdk eclipse editor by right clicking on project and run as Android Application, but still, i get an  error if try >phonegap run android in terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Not to be prickly about this, but it sounds like a new issue. I would recommend a new SO question for that.